# spring boot with embedded tomcat v8 is not decoding query paramter in linux enviroment

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat8

I am facing issue in decoding query parameter in a `GET` call only on Linux environment. The same setup works fine in my local setup (Intellij on Windows with `fileEncoding = UTF-8`).

My setup is using the following versions:

1. spring-boot v1.3.2RELEASE
2. Tomcat v8.0.30
3. Using feign client to call the service, which is encoding the request params correctly.
4. Other special annotation being used in my app is `@EnableEurekaClient` &
   `@EnableDiscoveryClient`

I can see that `OrderedCharacterEncodingFilter` is getting invoked in the request processing (number 3 in the filter chain).

And yes `URLDecoder.decode(value,"UTF-8");` definetly works, but I believe that there is something not working properly when its deployed to Linux box and may be a configuration would be required to make it work.

`

```
@RestController
    @RequestMapping("/api")
    @Slf4j
    public class HelloWorldController {


        @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String helloWorld(@RequestParam(value = "param1") String param1,@RequestParam(value = "param2") String param2,@RequestParam(value = "param3") String param3){
log.info("received param1: {}, param2: {}, param3: {}",param1,param2,param3);   
return "Hello";
}}
```

`

If we send `param1 = C+J` , on wire it is being sent as `C%2BJ` (expected), but in the controller I am expecting it to be back to `C+J` but I am getting `C%2BJ`.

Embedded tomcat is version 8 visit https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding#Q2 for encoding details, so by default `URIencoding` is `UTF-8`.

While running in linux, I did use `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` and following are other relevant properties that I checked.

- `Charset.defaultCharset()` UTF-8
- `sun.jnu.encoding` UTF-8